# how to fix error in my PUT function (views.py)?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make a simple restful API (CRUD) using Django and Django-rest-framework. The delete, update and post works but the put function is the problem.

I tried to comment each part of that and every time I try to run server it gives me some errors. 
The first error is gives me is:

> from article.views import ArticleView
>   File "C:\Users\Amirhossein.DESKTOP-FA436E8\Desktop\Simple -API\project\article\views.py", line 33
>   if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Even though I had used this syntax in my POST method and it worked.

Then I tried to comment this part of my code and it gave me back this error:

> from article.views import ArticleView
>   File "C:\Users\Amirhossein.DESKTOP-FA436E8\Desktop\Simple -API\project\article\views.py", line 37
>   def delete(self, request, pk):
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Here is my code:

```
def put(self, request, pk):
    saved_article = get_object_or_404(Article.objects.all(), pk=pk)
    data = request.data.get('article')
    serializer = ArticleSerializer(instance=saved_article, data=data, partial=True
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
        article_saved = serializer.save()
    return Response({"success": "Article '{}' updated successfully".format(article_saved.title)})
```

Here is the picture of my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBasf.png)

Comment: Did you forgot closing `)` before `if` statement?

Comment: Close  ) before if statement on line 32 for ArticleSerializer.

Comment: Guys, it seems this is a new user, can we please be little nice and give some space for improvement ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing parentheses

```
serializer = ArticleSerializer(instance=saved_article, data=data, partial=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the serializer line you forgot the closing parentheses

Change

```
serializer = ArticleSerializer(instance=saved_article, data=data, partial=True
```

to this

```
serializer = ArticleSerializer(instance=saved_article, data=data, partial=True)
```